# A way to grep using regular expresion to receive a dataframe or a list in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
peptide <- c("aaa(0.011)bbb(0.989)ccc","aaa(1)bbbccc","aaabbb(0.15)ccc(0.85)ddd",
             "aaabbb(0.75)cc(0.24)ddd(0.01)")
```

I would like to extract the text flanking each of the brackets. Sometimes there are up to 7 sets of brackets in each string (in my example there is a maximum of 3). While extracting the text, I would like to get rid of the brackets and numbers all together, and just keep the letters. Let’s say I want to extract up to five letters on each side of each bracket pair. If I achieved that, my output would look like this:

```
col1          col2        col3
aaabbbcc      aabbbccc    NA
aaabbbcc      NA          NA
aabbbcccdd   bbcccddd    NA
aabbbccddd   bbbccddd    ccddd
```

Where each row corresponds to strings extracted from one peptide.

I am quite new to R, and completely new to grep/sub, and am unable to find a way to grep into a data-frame.

The closest thing I came up with is this:

```
before<- sub(".*([[:print:]][[:print:]][[:print:]][[:print:]][[:print:]])\\(.*","\\1", peptide)
after<- sub(".*\\)([[:print:]][[:print:]][[:print:]][[:print:]][[:print:]]).*","\\1", peptide)
final <- paste(before,after,sep="")
```

This does not return what I want.

```
> final
[1] "1)bbbbbb(0"        "aaa(1)bbbcccbbbcc" "5)cccccc(0"        "75)cccc(0."
```

First, it just returns one string per peptide, while I would want it to return as many strings as there are pairs of brackets. Second, I know that my regular expressions are not correct - I do not omit numbers and brackets, and I would like to.

EDIT: I edited the output, because there was a typo in it, and I removed a mention to another question that I have not had time to ask before receiving answers here!

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Try `gsub("[().[:digit:]]*", "", peptide)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas - this gives me a character vector with df$peptides strings but without brackets.

Comment: how are you getting 4 bs in col1 row 3?

Comment: In the question you say you *would like to get rid of the brackets*. Do you want to keep them? If yes,  `gsub("[.[:digit:]]*", "", peptide)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas - I would like to receive an output like in the output example I showed. Which means a dataframe

Comment: @rawr - there should be 3 bs, sorry for the confusion, will edit this now!

Comment: @RuiBarradas - sorry I wasn't clean in my previous comment.  I would like to receive an output like in the output example I showed - extracting text around each of the brackets in each string. Which means a dataframe must be an output (or a matrix)

Comment: Heello, i am sorry, I am going to accept it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define `sep` to be any character that does not appear in `peptide`.  We used a space below.

Then create two variables in which the numeric fields have been removed and the parentheses around them have been removed too.  `p0` is precisely that while `ps` is like `p0` but the last character of each of the non-numeric fields is replaced with `sep` (so that we can later locate it).

Using the above variables compute `pos` which is a numeric matrix whose ith column contains the character positions of the end of the ith fields in `p0`.  To do this we use `gregexpr` to find the locations of `sep` in `ps` and then manipulate that into a numeric matrix `pos`.

Then for each element of `pos` determine the character positions of the corresponding output string's start and end and use `substring` to extract those substrings from `p0` reshaping to the same dimensions as `pos`.

```
sep <- " "
pat <- "(.)\\(.*?\\)"
ps <- gsub(pat, sep, peptide)
p0 <- gsub(pat, "\\1", peptide)

g <- gregexpr(sep, ps, fixed = TRUE)
pos <- t(unname(do.call("cbind", lapply(g, ts))))

replace(pos, TRUE, substring(p0, pos-5+1, pos+5))
```

giving:

```
     [,1]         [,2]       [,3]   
[1,] "aaabbbcc"   "aabbbccc" NA     
[2,] "aaabbbcc"   NA         NA     
[3,] "aabbbcccdd" "bbcccddd" NA     
[4,] "aabbbccddd" "bbbccddd" "ccddd"
```

Comment: Hello. It took me some time to test this, and I like your response most - because it is very neat/elegant, but in addition I will actually make an additional use of the matrix pos. I wonder could you please explain the regular expression pat that you use? it is obviously exactly what I want, but I would like to understand it. Another question is - what is the ts argument in lapply? Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, I have another question. is there a simple way to indicate that the number of characters grepped was lower than 5? For example, for the last [4,3] cell in the output matrix it would be something like "ccdddXXXXX" where X indicates that there were no characters to grep from the original string?

Comment: `cbind` applied to ordinary vectors of different lengths recycles them (which is not what we want) whereas `cbind.ts` will add NAs to the end of the short ones (which is what we want).  The `lapply` creates a list of `ts` objects so that the `cbind.ts` method is invoked.

Comment: Regarding second question use ` peptide <- paste0("XXXXX", peptide, "XXXXX")` in place of `peptide` and then run the code.

Comment: The regular expression matches any character `(.)` followed by a left paren and then the shortest string of any characters until a right paren and then the right paren. The first `gsub` replaces the entire match with `sep` and the second `gsub`  replaces the entire match with the first character. The second `gsub` is the same as `gsub("\\(.*?\\)", "", peptide)` but it was done that way so that we can reuse the same pattern rather than have two different patterns.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to use `strsplit` using the numbers/parens as separators:

```
str(
  strsplit(peptide, '[().[:digit:]]+')
)
# List of 4
#  $ : chr [1:3] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "aaa" "bbbccc"
#  $ : chr [1:3] "aaabbb" "ccc" "ddd"
#  $ : chr [1:3] "aaabbb" "cc" "ddd"
```

This looks good so far, so we can now iterate over each break and grab the before/after concatenations. (Ignore for now the `removeqmark=` option, I'll justify it in a moment.)

```
surrounding <- function(vec, k=5, removeqmark=TRUE) {
  l <- length(vec)
  out <- sapply(seq_len(l-1), function(i) {
    bef <- paste(vec[1:i], collapse="")
    aft <- paste(vec[(i+1):l], collapse="")
    paste0(substr(bef, max(1, nchar(bef)-k+1), nchar(bef)),
           substr(aft, 1, min(k, nchar(aft))))
  })
  if (removeqmark) out <- gsub("\\?", "", out)
  out
}
```

Now we can iterate over the split-string vectors using this function:

```
str(
  lapply(strsplit(peptide, '[().[:digit:]]+'), surrounding)
)
# List of 4
#  $ : chr [1:2] "aaabbbcc" "aabbbccc"
#  $ : chr "aaabbbcc"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "aabbbcccdd" "bbcccddd"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "aabbbccddd" "bbbccddd"
```

Unfortunately, it's dropping the third of the last vector. This is not surprising to me, since ending on a separator does not necessarily return an empty string. So we can add something to each string IFF we are ending on a separator:

```
( peptide2 <- gsub("([().[:digit:]])$", "\\1?", peptide) )
# [1] "aaa(0.011)bbb(0.989)ccc"        "aaa(1)bbbccc"                   "aaabbb(0.15)ccc(0.85)ddd"      
# [4] "aaabbb(0.75)cc(0.24)ddd(0.01)?"
str(
  strsplit(peptide2, '[().[:digit:]]+')
)
# List of 4
#  $ : chr [1:3] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "aaa" "bbbccc"
#  $ : chr [1:3] "aaabbb" "ccc" "ddd"
#  $ : chr [1:4] "aaabbb" "cc" "ddd" "?"
str(
  lapply(strsplit(peptide2, '[().[:digit:]]+'), surrounding)
)
# List of 4
#  $ : chr [1:2] "aaabbbcc" "aabbbccc"
#  $ : chr "aaabbbcc"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "aabbbcccdd" "bbcccddd"
#  $ : chr [1:3] "aabbbccddd" "bbbccddd" "ccddd"
```

where our default is to remove the question mark from the resulting surrounds. To use a different surrounding number than 5, just do:

```
lapply(strsplit(peptide2, '[().[:digit:]]+'), surrounding, k=2)
```

In order to combine this into a data.frame, you need some more work, since you have rows of different lengths.

```
rows <- lapply(strsplit(peptide2, '[().[:digit:]]+'), surrounding)
( maxrows <- max(lengths(rows)) )
# [1] 3
rows <- lapply(rows, function(r) c(r, rep(NA_character_, maxrows - length(r))))
do.call(rbind, rows)
#      [,1]         [,2]       [,3]   
# [1,] "aaabbbcc"   "aabbbccc" NA     
# [2,] "aaabbbcc"   NA         NA     
# [3,] "aabbbcccdd" "bbcccddd" NA     
# [4,] "aabbbccddd" "bbbccddd" "ccddd"
```

(This is generating a `matrix` ... sandwich in `as.data.frame` if you need a frame.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function that will create a left- and right-side for each set of brackets (so you will get `n - 1` strings for `n` brackets) and collapse everything to the left and right with a comma. Then just sub out at most 5 characters from each side of the comma.

```
peptide <- c("aaa(0.011)bbb(0.989)ccc","aaa(1)bbbccc","aaabbb(0.15)ccc(0.85)ddd",
             "aaabbb(0.75)cc(0.24)ddd(0.01)")


f <- function(x) {
  l <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(ii) {
    x <- rbind(trimws(x), replace(gsub('.', '', x), ii, ','))
    paste(x, collapse = '')
  })

  sapply(l[-length(l)], function(x)
    gsub('([a-z]{1,5}),([a-z]{1,5})?|.', '\\1\\2', x))
}


sp <- strsplit(gsub('\\([0-9.]+\\)', ', ', peptide), ',')

## for example
f(sp[[4L]])
# [1] "aabbbccddd" "bbbccddd"   "ccddd"     

## apply to everything and return as a data frame
l <- lapply(sp, f)
l <- lapply(l, function(x) {
  ml <- max(lengths(l))
  setNames(`length<-`(x, ml), paste0('col', seq.int(ml)))
})
data.frame(do.call('rbind', l))

#         col1     col2  col3
# 1   aaabbbcc aabbbccc  <NA>
# 2   aaabbbcc     <NA>  <NA>
# 3 aabbbcccdd bbcccddd  <NA>
# 4 aabbbccddd bbbccddd ccddd
```